# Using async.waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I'm using node.js and the async package.

Here's the code I have:

```
async.waterfall(
[
    function(callback) {
        var data = getSomeData();
        callback(null, data);
    },
    function(data, callback) {
        someFunctionThatNeedsData(data);
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
],
function(err, result) {
}
);
```

`getSomeData` has an asynchronous HTTP request that grabs some data from a web service.  I'd like to wait until I get a response, and then return that data and pass it to `someFunctionThatNeedsData`.

What I expected was that `getSomeData` -- including the callback inside of it -- would have to complete before moving on to invoke `someFunctionThatNeedsData`.

The problem is that, despite using the `waterfall` function here, `data` is undefined by the time it gets to `someFunctionThatNeedsData`.

Additionally, from `console.log` I can see that the end of `getSomeData` is reached before the callback inside of `getSomeData` even begins.

Am I using `waterfall` incorrectly, or is it just not the right tool here?  If it's just not right, what can I use to achieve the desired effect?

Or do I have to resign to having deeply nested callbacks (which, with future work, I will) and have to just mitigate it by extracting inline code into named functions?

Comment: if getSomeData is an asynchronous method, the expectation from that method would be that you don't return data rather take a callback to return data. And then on return of the data, you invoke "callback" to move to next function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> getSomeData() has an asynchronous http request that grabs some data from a web service.

This is the issue. The execution flow already continued to the callback and executed it. This is how asynchronous functions work!

You have to pass the callback to `getSomeData`, which calls it once the HTTP request finished. So yes: You may need to nest the callbacks.

Comment: So there is no way to prevent getSomeData from returning before the http request's callback has been called?

Comment: @user3183922 Except for making a synchronous request (which you should *not*): No.

Comment: OK.  I come from a Java background, so I am probably (as I suspected) trying to force patterns that aren't possible in a Javascript/node.js context.

Are there any other major reasons to not make synchronous requests, other than that you could end up blocking your whole app if it takes a while to return?

Comment: @user3183922 I cannot think of any at the moment, but that one certainly is a big one.

Comment: @user3183922 Most JS/node.js libraries are created with asynchronous design. You should design your JS/node.js app with this mindset.

Answer (score 0):

If you have async operation. You don't necessary to use async.waterfall. You could just do that in a promise chain style.

```
getSomeData().then(function(data) 
{
    var changeData = changeYourData(data);
    return changeData;
}).then(function(changedData)
{
    // some more stuff with it. You can keep on forwarding to the next `then` 
}).catch(function(err)
{
    // if any error throw at any point will get catch here
}).finally(function() 
{
    // this one will guarantee get call no matter what,
    // exactly the same like async.waterfall end of chain callback
});
```

This example will work with [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), [When](https://github.com/cujojs/when), and any promise lib that follow standard.

If you need to use async.waterfall (because you could drive it with an Array.map) 
You just need to callback in your `then`

```
async.waterfall(
[
    function(callback) {
        // A 
        getSomeData().then(function(data)
        {
            callback(null, data);
        });
        // B - just throw the whole thing in
        callback(null , getSomeData());
    },
    function(data, callback) {
        // A
        someFunctionThatNeedsData(data);
        // B
        data.then(function(resolvedData)
        {
             someFunctionThatNeedsData(resolvedData);
             callback(null, 'done');
        });
    }
],
function(err, result) {
});
```

Hope this help.